# Why is list::remove_if() giving me an error?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was making a chess engine and I have a list of moves.

```
std::list<Move> moves;
```

I also have a function that checks if the king is under a check after a specific move.

```
bool Board::check_after_move(const Move& move)
{
    Board temp=*this;
    temp.DoMove(move);
    return temp.check();
}
```

After I generate possible moves, I filter out the illegal ones.

```
moves.remove_if(check_after_move);
```

But I get an error

```
'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

How should I fix this?

Edit:
This is another error I get

```
'std::list<Move,std::allocator<Move>>::remove_if': no matching overloaded function found
```

Comment: Is it possible to post a small code sample that reproduces the error when I compile it?

Comment: also as an irrelevant side note, you'll still want to erase as well. Look up "erase remove idiom"

Comment: @KennyOstrom That is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check_after_move` is a non-static member function, so you cannot make a basic function pointer from it.

The easiest general solution is to pass a lambda that captures `this`:

```
moves.remove_if([this](const Move& move) { return check_after_move(move); });
```

Or you can bind the `this` pointer directly:

```
moves.remove_if(std::bind(&check_after_move, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```